# What are the differences between skiddies and programmers

Tags: label, title

I've seen the labels tossed around freely but describing the differences between the two has left me flabbergasted. What are some defining characteristics of skiddies that differentiate between programmers?

Comment: "skiddies"? You mean "script kiddies"?

Answer (score 2):

If by "skiddies" you mean what I've heard called "script kiddies," I think of them as people that find example code (mostly scripts) and use them to accomplish their tasks without really understanding the code's meaning.  Typically, a script kiddie copies and pastes code rather than writing it from scratch.

Comment: +1. To add to that, I'd say there's a fine line between a script kiddie and a "cargo cult programmer".

Comment: I agree, I think we should be able to distinguish skiddies and cargo cult programmers.